# Cisco 1841/WAP4410N Wireless Access Issue

Tags: dhcp, ip, cisco-wireless

In our environment, we have a Cisco 1841 which, among other things, performs DHCP services for a small manufacturing facility. We have 100 available DHCP addresses in the pool. That device connects to a Dell 2824, which serves our static devices across the location. Also connected to the Dell switch are several Cisco WAP4410N access points.

Our issue is that we can connect to our system wirelessly, but only if we put a static address into the adapter. Using DHCP, we can connect over Ethernet ONLY, but not over the WLAN. We do get a connection to the AP, but we get an APIPA address. 'show ip dhcp bindings' shows that I have only used about 40 of our 100 addresses.

Any idea why our devices cannot use DHCP over the WLAN? I'm stumped here.

EDIT:I have since found out that DHCP is NOT working via Ethernet either, at least not consistently.

EDIT 2: Config posted below:

```
;WAP4410N Configuration File - Version: 2.0.4.2
;MAC address: 44:2B:03:7F:00:A6
;WPS PIN: 30978577
;The checksum: 855329  


[BASIC]

Host_Name=HOSTNAME

Device_Name=WAP4410N

Language=en

IP_settings=0 ;0:static; 1:automatic

Ipv4_address=192.168.2.244

Ipv4_subnet_mask=255.255.255.0

IPv4_default_gateway=192.168.2.254

IPv4_Primary_DNS=192.168.0.2

IPv4_Secondary_DNS=0.0.0.0

IPv6=0 ;0:disabled; 1:enabled

Ipv6_address=

Ipv6_prefix_length=0

IPv6_default_gateway=

IPv6_Primary_DNS=

IPv6_Secondary_DNS=



[Time]

Time_setting=1 ;0: manually, 1:automatically

Date=2015/09/23 ;yyyy/mm/dd

Time=08:27:24 ;hh:mm:ss

Time_zone=010-06:00 

daylight_saving=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

User_Defined_NTP=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

User_NTP=



[Setup_advanced]

Force_Fast_Ethernet=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

Ethernet_Auto_Negotiation=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

Administrative_Port_Speed=0 ;0:10M, 1:100M, 2:1000M

Administrative_Duplex_Mode=1 ;0:Half Duplex, 1:Full Duplex

Bonjour=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

HTTP_Redirect=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

HTTP_Redirect_URL=

802.1x_supplicant=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

Via_mac_authentication=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

Username=

Password=



[Wireless_Basic]

Network_mode=7 ;0:Disable; 1: b only; 2: g only; 3: n only; 4: B/G mixed; 7:B/G/N mixed

Channel=6 ; 0..14; 0: auto channel

SSID1=HOSTNAME

SSID1_broadcast=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

SSID2=

SSID2_broadcast=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

SSID3=

SSID3_broadcast=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

SSID4=

SSID4_broadcast=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled



[Radius_Server]

Primary_radius_server=

Primary_port_no=1812

Primary_shared_secret=

Secondary_radius_server=

Secondary_port_no=1812

Secondary_shared_secret=



[Wireless_security_1]

;for SSID1

ssid=HOSTNAME

isolation_between_SSID=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

security_mode=1 ;1: WEP, 2: WPA-Personal, 3: WPA2-Personal, 4: WPA2-Personal Mixed, 5: WPA-Enterprise,

    6: WPA2-Enterprise, 7: WPA2-Enterprise Mixed, 8:RADIUS, 0: Disabled

isolation_within_SSID=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

authentication_type=1 ;0:open system; 1:shared key

encryption=64 ;64: 64 bit WEP, 128:128 bit WEP, 1: TKP, 2: AES, 3: AES+TKIP

Default_Tx_key=1 ; 1..4

key1=********** ;in Hex

key2= ;in Hex

key3= ;in Hex

key4= ;in Hex

PSK_key= ;in ASCII; The length of the key is from 8 to 64

Key_renew=3600 ;in seconds



[Wireless_security_2]

;for SSID2

ssid=

isolation_between_SSID=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

security_mode=0 ;1: WEP, 2: WPA-Personal, 3: WPA2-Personal, 4: WPA2-Personal Mixed, 5: WPA-Enterprise,

    6: WPA2-Enterprise, 7: WPA2-Enterprise Mixed, 8:RADIUS, 0: Disabled

isolation_within_SSID=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

authentication_type=0 ;0:open system; 1:shared key

encryption=0 ;64: 64 bit WEP, 128:128 bit WEP, 1: TKP, 2: AES, 3: AES+TKIP

Default_Tx_key=0 ; 1..4

key1= ;in Hex

key2= ;in Hex

key3= ;in Hex

key4= ;in Hex

PSK_key= ;in ASCII; The length of the key is from 8 to 63

Key_renew=0 ;in seconds



[Wireless_security_3]

;for SSID3

ssid=

isolation_between_SSID=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

security_mode=0 ;1: WEP, 2: WPA-Personal, 3: WPA2-Personal, 4: WPA2-Personal Mixed, 5: WPA-Enterprise,

    6: WPA2-Enterprise, 7: WPA2-Enterprise Mixed, 8:RADIUS, 0: Disabled

isolation_within_SSID=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

authentication_type=0 ;0:open system; 1:shared key

encryption=0 ;64: 64 bit WEP, 128:128 bit WEP, 1: TKP, 2: AES, 3: AES+TKIP

Default_Tx_key=0 ; 1..4

key1= ;in Hex

key2= ;in Hex

key3= ;in Hex

key4= ;in Hex

PSK_key= ;in ASCII; The length of the key is from 8 to 63

Key_renew=0 ;in seconds



[Wireless_security_4]

;for SSID4

ssid=

isolation_between_SSID=1 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

security_mode=0 ;1: WEP, 2: WPA-Personal, 3: WPA2-Personal, 4: WPA2-Personal Mixed, 5: WPA-Enterprise,

    6: WPA2-Enterprise, 7: WPA2-Enterprise Mixed, 8:RADIUS, 0: Disabled

isolation_within_SSID=0 ;0:disabled, 1:enabled

authentication_type=0 ;0:open system; 1:shared key

encryption=0 ;64: 64 bit WEP, 128:128 bit WEP, 1: TKP, 2: AES, 3: AES+TKIP

Default_Tx_key=0 ; 1..4

key1= ;in Hex

key2= ;in Hex

key3= ;in Hex

key4= ;in Hex

PSK_key= ;in ASCII; The length of the key is from 8 to 63

Key_renew=0 ;in seconds



[Wireless_Connection_Control_1]

;for SSID1

Connection_Control=0 ;0: disabled, 1:local, 2: Radius

Control_type=1 ;0: allowed the following local mac, 1: prevent the following local mac

Mac_01=

Mac_02=

Mac_03=

Mac_04=

Mac_05=

Mac_06=

Mac_07=

Mac_08=

Mac_09=

Mac_10=

Mac_11=

Mac_12=

Mac_13=

Mac_14=

Mac_15=

Mac_16=

Mac_17=

Mac_18=

Mac_19=

Mac_20=



[Wireless_Connection_Control_2]

;for SSID2

Connection_Control=0 ;0: disabled, 1:local, 2: Radius

Control_type=0 ;0: allowed the following local mac, 1: prevent the following local mac

Mac_01=

Mac_02=

Mac_03=

Mac_04=

Mac_05=

Mac_06=

Mac_07=

Mac_08=

Mac_09=

Mac_10=

Mac_11=

Mac_12=

Mac_13=

Mac_14=

Mac_15=

Mac_16=

Mac_17=

Mac_18=

Mac_19=

Mac_20=



[Wireless_Connection_Control_3]

;for SSID3

Connection_Control=0 ;0: disabled, 1:local, 2: Radius

Control_type=0 ;0: allowed the following local mac, 1: prevent the following local mac

Mac_01=

Mac_02=

Mac_03=

Mac_04=

Mac_05=

Mac_06=

Mac_07=

Mac_08=

Mac_09=

Mac_10=

Mac_11=

Mac_12=

Mac_13=

Mac_14=

Mac_15=

Mac_16=

Mac_17=

Mac_18=

Mac_19=

Mac_20=



[Wireless_Connection_Control_4]

;for SSID4

Connection_Control=0 ;0: disabled, 1:local, 2: Radius

Control_type=0 ;0: allowed the following local mac, 1: prevent the following local mac

Mac_01=

Mac_02=

Mac_03=

Mac_04=

Mac_05=

Mac_06=

Mac_07=

Mac_08=

Mac_09=

Mac_10=

Mac_11=

Mac_12=

Mac_13=

Mac_14=

Mac_15=

Mac_16=

Mac_17=

Mac_18=

Mac_19=

Mac_20=



[VLAN_QoS]

VLAN=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled

Default_VLAN_ID=0 ;1..4094

VLAN_Tag=0 ;0:untagged, 1: tagged

AP_Management_VLAN=0 ;1..4094

VLAN_tag_over_WDS=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled

WDS_VLAN_List= ;a,b,...,"a" is a VLAN ID. Different IDs divided by ",". 4 VLAN IDs should be set at most

VLAN_ID_4_SSID1=0 ;1..4094

Priority_4_SSID1=0 ;0..7

WMM_4_SSID1=1 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled

VLAN_ID_4_SSID2=0 ;1..4094

Priority_4_SSID2=0 ;0..7

WMM_4_SSID2=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled

VLAN_ID_4_SSID3=0 ;1..4094

Priority_4_SSID3=0 ;0..7

WMM_4_SSID3=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled

VLAN_ID_4_SSID4=0 ;1..4094

Priority_4_SSID4=0 ;0..7

WMM_4_SSID4=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled



[Wireless_Advanced]

802.11d=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled

Country_Region=840 ;840: United States. It°Øs read only

Channel_bandwidth=1 ;0: auto, 1: 20MHz, 2: 40MHz

Guard_Interval=0 ;0: auto, 1: 400ns, 2: 800ns

CTS_Protection_Mode=0 ;0: disable, 1: auto

beacon_interval=100 ;20..1000

DTIM_interval=1 ;1..255

rts_threshold=2347 ;1..2347

fragmentation_threshold=2346 ;256..2346

Load_balance=0 ;0: disabled, 1:enabled

Load_threshold_4_SSD1=

Load_threshold_4_SSD2=

Load_threshold_4_SSD3=

Load_threshold_4_SSD4=



[AP_Mode]

AP_mode=0 ;0: Access Point, 1: WDS repeater, 2: WDS bridge, 3: Universal bridge, 4: Monitor

MAC1=

MAC2=

MAC3=

MAC4=

Allow_WDS_repeater=0 ;0:disabled, 1: enabled

Universal_repeater=0 ;0:disabled, 1: enabled

Preferred_SSID= ;for universal bridge

No_Security=0 ;1: view it as a rogue AP. 0: don°Øt

No_in_Legal_AP_List=0 ;1: view it as a rogue AP. 0: don°Øt

Legal_AP_List_entry_no=0 ;0..255

Legal_AP=



[Management]

secret_shown=0 ;0: show clear text, 1: just show ********

username=*

AP_password=*

HTTPS_Access=0 ;0:disabled, 1: enabled

Wireless_Web_Access=0 ;0:disabled, 1: enabled

Secure_Shell=0 ;0:disabled, 1: enabled

SNMP=0 ;0:disabled, 1: enabled

Contact=

Device_Name=

Location=

Get_Community=

Set_Community=

Trap_Community=

SNMP_Trusted_Any_Host=0 ;0:disabled, 1: enabled

SNMP_Trusted_Host_start_IP=

SNMP_Trusted_Host_range=0 ;0..255

Trap_Destination=



[Log]

E-mail_alert=0 ;0:disabled, 1: enabled

SMTP_server=

Email_address_for_logs=

Log_queue_length=0

Log_time_threshold=0

Syslog=0 ;0:disabled, 1: enabled

Syslog_server_IP=

Unathorized_login_attempt=0 ;0:no log, 1: log

Authorized_Login=0 ;0:no log, 1: log

System_error_message=0 ;0:no log, 1: log

Configuration_changes=0 ;0:no log, 1: log
```

Comment: Can you post the AP config?

Comment: OK, then let's fix your DHCP first.   Do you have wireshark?  Can you capture a (failed) DHCP transaction?

Comment: I have it on another device, but not on any in my office at the moment. Let me install and capture a DHCP transaction, and I will reply shortly.

Comment: One other observation... if I disable dhcp (no service dhcp), and re-enable it, my DHCP starts to work again, if only temporarily. At some point, it stops accepting new clients, even though I have quite a few leases available. I will continue to monitor, and I will troubleshoot with Wireshark once it stops working again.